# How to convert a datetime into timestamp with timezone(Asia/Dubai) included?

Tags: python, python-2.7, date, datetime

I am able to convert to date from a timestamp, but the conversion from datetime to timestamp is giving wrong answer. here's my code

```
import datetime
from pytz import timezone

datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1426017600,timezone("Asia/Dubai")).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
output:'2015-03-11 00:00:00'
```

How to include timezone when converting back to timestamp from datetime ?

```
>>datetime.datetime(2015,03,11).strftime('%s')
output:1426012200
```

Comment: Another SO answer has what you're looking for [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18646797/943773). Look at the second part about converting from local time to another timezone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime, time, date
from pytz import timezone, utc

tz = timezone("Asia/Dubai")
d = datetime.fromtimestamp(1426017600,tz)
print d
midnight = tz.localize(datetime.combine(date(d.year, d.month, d.day),time(0,0)), is_dst=None)
print int((midnight - datetime(1970, 1, 1, tzinfo=utc)).total_seconds())
```

Based on code from [python - datetime with timezone to epoch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12165691/python-datetime-with-timezone-to-epoch)