# filtering recoreds through date range in django view

Tags: django, view, filter

I'm trying to filter data through view. I tried the __range and __gte + __lte but there are not results on the website.

model:

```
class Change(models.Model):
  def __unicode__(self):
    return unicode(self.number)
  number = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="CHG")
  service = models.ForeignKey('organization.Service')
  environment = models.CharField(choices=ENV_CHOICE, max_length=20)
  description = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  start_date = models.DateField()
  start_time = models.TimeField()
  end_date = models.DateField()
  end_time = models.TimeField()
  assignee = models.ForeignKey('organization.Assignee')
```

I tried different approach with the view:

## 1

```
def home(request):
  changes = Change.objects.all().filter(start_date__gte=datetime.date.today(), end_date__lte=datetime.date.today())
  return render(request, 'index.html', {'changes' : changes})
```

In this case when only start_date__gte is used it's working correctly but when I add the end_date__lte it does not display any records.

## 2

```
def home(request):
  today = datetime.date.today()
  changes = Change.objects.all(today__range=[start_date, end_date])
  return render(request, 'index.html', {'changes' : changes})
```

In this case I get and error global name start_date is not defined.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: What result are you trying to get from your data? Can you please post examples.

Comment: @Wtower I would like to query all the records from change database and check if there are any changes scheduled for today. Sometimes change is scheduled for more than one day so I would like to have it listed on the website until the scheduled end date. For example number = 765432, ... , start_date = 2015-11-19, ... , end_date = 2015-11-22, ...
And during the date range (19, 20, 21, 22) I want to have it displayed on the website. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that in your above code, timedelta(Difference between start and end date) between start and end date is 0. If your start and end date is same, you should add some timedelta in your end time like this.

```
def home(request):
    changes = Change.objects.all().filter(start_date__gte=datetime.date.today(), \
              end_date__lte=datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=86400))
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'changes' : changes})
```

Comment: I tried to change it to add time delta but unfortunately it does not return any results. The start_date = 2015-11-19 and end_date = 2015-11-22.

Comment: Is the format of date in db is same as you are writing in your query i.e. yy-mm-dd?

Comment: Yes, it is. The strange thing is that if I will only use start_date__gte=datetime.date.today() in filter it works. It display records that are greater or equal todays date, but when I want to limit it with end_date__lte no records are displayed. Both start_date and end_date are models.DateField().

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you don't understand how `range` lookup works.
It is used like this:

```
Change.objects.filter(change_field__range=[start_datatime, end_datetime])
```

where `change_field` is a datetime or date field of `Change` model on which you want to query. `start_datetime` and `end_datetime` are datetime objects which you provide. For example:

```
class Change(models.Mode):
    ...
    published = models.DateTimeField()
    ...
```

so your query may look like

```
Change.objects.filter(published__range=[datetime.datetime(2011, 2, 4), datetime.datetime(2011, 5,4)])
```

This will return queryset with `Change` objects which were published between `2011-2-4` and `2011-5-4`

Comment: Sweet, but I would like change_field to be equal todays day (which means that it will be dynamically assigned every day. That's why I thought that I can define the variable in the view and pass it to Change.objects.filter. Then I would like to have a datetime objects that define the range and they come from database (start_date and end_date) of the model. I do not want to provide static values.

Comment: @hplodur, `change_filed` is a field, not a value, you can't filter objects without a field so  you won't do this as you want. What you need to do is to create a range where `start_datetime` is beginning of the current day and `end_datetime` is the end of the day. Here is how you can archive this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14972802/determine-start-and-end-time-of-current-day-utc-est-utc-python

Comment: So, how do you query a table for say **price** data with **valid_from** and **valid_to** dates?I want to find a valid **price** for a **reference date** (eg. today's date), how would you procee d to do that?