# Inclusive date ranges in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, time

I didn't phrase this question correctly and as a result, none of the answers quite hit the mark.

What I wanted to know is, what's the best way to get `time` to return the end of a day in epoch milliseconds, if given just the date, rather than both date and time?

Here's how I'm doing it at the moment:

```
def get_epoch_endofday(day):
    return time.mktime(time.strptime('005923'+day,"%S%M%H%d%m%y"))*1000
```

The function takes the date in the form ddmmyy, and then spits out the epoch milliseconds on that day at 23:59:00.

I wondered, is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want. Can you add an example of the kind of values you are looking for? What second date, why is `00:00` exclusive?

Comment: And if you are working with just dates, why not use `datetime.date()` objects?

Comment: More precisely what value should `day` have and what you expect as a return value from `get_epoch`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Please see my edit. The dataset has the dates recorded in epoch miliseconds.

Comment: @GentiSaliu - I've completely rephrased my question. Please let me know if you still need more context.

Comment: You want to create an interval: beginning should be for eg. `2016-04-16 00:00:00`, end `2016-04-17 23:59:59`. Now you get for the end part `2016-04-17 00:00:00`, correct?

Comment: @GentiSaliu - correct

Comment: The end of the interval should be on the same day, just 23 hours, 59 minutes, 59 seconds later?

Comment: @GentiSaliu - It should be at the end of the day which I specify, yes.

Comment: If any of the answers given below address your question, pease mark it as such, so that the thread is closed and removed from the board. Otherwise, please elaborate. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It wasn't very clear at first, but you want to create an interval for a given day (say `2016-02-14`), which contains the first and last instant of that day. That means:

First instant: `2016-02-14 00:00:00.000`

Last instant: `2016-02-14 23:59:59.999`

The function below returns that interval as a tupel. It works like this:

- create the `start` of the interval by creating a new date instance on the same day with hours, minutes and milliseconds all set to `0`
- create an interval spanning `23` hours, `59` minutes, `59` seconds and `999999` microseconds
- add this interval to the beginning of the day

Code:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# 2016-02-08 11:39:31.093209
day = datetime.now()

def get_day_interval(day):
    start = datetime(day.year, day.month, day.day)
    interval = timedelta(seconds=59, microseconds=999999, minutes=59, hours=23)
    return (start, start + interval)

(start, end) = get_day_interval(day)

# 2016-02-08 00:00:00
print(start)

# 2016-02-08 23:59:59.999999
print(end)
```

Consult the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) for more options.

If the interval can be exclusive, the code becomes simpler, see the summary of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14972866/277106).

Answer (score 2):

## Generators

Here is how you can create a function that produces an inclusive range:

```
def inc_range(stop, start=0, step=1):
    numerator = start

    while numerator<=stop:
        yield numerator
        numerator += step


a = [val for val in inc_range(10)]
print(a)
```

Displays:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Now this method can be adapted for anything you want; date or otherwise.

## Date range generator

Here it the method tailored to your needs:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta 


def date_range(stop, start, step=1):
    delta_date = stop - start
    numerator = 0

    while numerator <= delta_date.days:
        yield str(start + timedelta(numerator))
        numerator += step


date_start = date(2014, 3, 15)
date_end = date(2014, 3, 21)

a = [val for val in date_range(date_end, date_start)]
print(a)
```

Displays:

```
['2014-03-15', '2014-03-16', '2014-03-17', '2014-03-18', '2014-03-19', '2014-03-20', '2014-03-21']
```

Note that if you don't include `str()` when yielding in the generator, the response would be an object of `datetime.date()`  instead.

Hope this answers your question.