# Select in Sqlite3

Tags: python, django, django-models, sqlite

I am using the `select` in sqlite3 statement to get rows from `django` db (default db)

```
p=connection.cursor().execute("SELECT * FROM webapp_information WHERE dat  BETWEEN date('now', 'start of day') AND date('now', 'localtime');")
a=p.fetchall()
for i in a:
  print(i)`
```

i get the dat(date field) from db but it returns nothing.

I tried in different way-

> In [206]: p=connection.cursor().execute("SELECT * FROM
>   webapp_information WHERE dat='2018-08-28';")

It returns with a empty list, however I pretty sure the date are stored in the it. 
Any help? thank you in advance.
Modules.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models 
import datetime

# Create your models here.

class information(models.Model):
login=models.CharField(max_length=100,)
idd=models.CharField(max_length=100,)
avatar_url=models.CharField(max_length=100,default='nll',null=True)
gravatar_id=models.CharField(max_length=100,default='nll',null=True)
url=models.CharField(max_length=100, default='nll',null=True)
html_url=models.CharField(max_length=100,default='nll',null=True)
followers_url=models.CharField(max_length=100,default='nll',null=True)
following_url=models.CharField(max_length=100,default='nll',null=True)
gists_url=models.CharField(max_length=100,default='nll',null=True)
starred_url=models.CharField(max_length=100,default='nll',null=True)
subscriptions_url=models.CharField(max_length=100,default='nll',null=True)
organizations_url=models.CharField(max_length=100,default='nll',null=True)
repos_url=models.CharField(max_length=100,default='nll',null=True)
events_url=models.CharField(max_length=100,default='nll',null=True)
received_events=models.CharField(max_length=100,default='nll',null=True)
typ=models.CharField(max_length=100,default='nll',null=True)
site_admin=models.CharField(max_length=100,default='nll',null=True)
name=models.CharField(max_length=100,default='nll',null=True)
company=models.CharField(max_length=100,default='nll',null=True)
blog=models.CharField(max_length=100,default='nll',null=True)
location=models.CharField(max_length=100,default='nll',null=True)
email=models.CharField(max_length=100,default='nll',null=True)
hireable=models.CharField(max_length=100,default='nll',null=True)
bio=models.CharField(max_length=100,default='nll',null=True)
public_repos=models.CharField(max_length=100,default='nll',null=True)
public_gists=models.CharField(max_length=100,default='nll',null=True)
followers=models.CharField(max_length=100,default='nll',null=True)
following=models.CharField(max_length=100,default='nll',null=True)
created_at=models.CharField(max_length=100,default='nll',null=True)
updated_at=models.CharField(max_length=100,default='nll',null=True)
dat = models.DateField()
class sapi(models.Model):
    dat = models.DateField()
```

Comment: Why are you doing this instead of using the models?

Comment: Use [Django ORM](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/)

Comment: I thought this way is easier and understandable quickly.. If you know how to do it please let me know thanks

Comment: please post a proper MVC if you hope to get a serious answer. This being said, I can only second Daniel Roseman and Marcos Schroh: if you're using Django with a relational database, not using the ORM is a complete WTF.

Comment: Oh and yes: sqlite is really a poor substitute for a proper SQL database, and can breaks in the most surprising ways... specially if you use it directly instead of using the ORM, it's really easy to insert invalid data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking to do something like this, with date ranges:

```
from webapp.models import Information

start_of_day_date = ...
now_date ...

p = Information.objects.filter(
    dat__range=(start_of_day_date, now_date),
)

for i in p:
    print(p)
```

For a good explanation on how to set `start_of_day_date` and `now_date`, see this post: [Determine start and end time of current day (UTC -> EST -> UTC) ; Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14972802/determine-start-and-end-time-of-current-day-utc-est-utc-python)

Good luck!

Comment: sir, i tried this method too.. the querryset is empty..Out[3]: <QuerySet []>  In modules.py, i declared  dat = models.DateField()    I do not know the reason..thanks

Comment: I checked the admin panel, there are many data that has dat values.. I use the search panel to search the dat field.. I registered the dat field in search_fields() method..in that also no result only empty

Comment: Have you tried it with a large date range, like `start_of_day_day = datetime.date(1800, 1, 1)` and `now_date = datetime.date(2200, 1, 1)`?

Comment: in [28]: p = information.objects.filter(
    dat__range=(datetime.date(2018, 8, 22), datetime.date(2018, 8, 28)),
)

In [29]: p
Out[29]: <QuerySet []> --- is that any mistake in configuring the modules.py. I will make uplaod the modules.py in the question. could you please tell me what is worng.. thanks