# Expand date to the beginning and end datetime for the day

Tags: python, datetime

Based on the current time (`datetime.now()`) I want to expand this to cover the whole days time.

Right now I have been using:

```
start = (datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
end = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Problem is that this is 24 hours from the current date. If it is 12pm noon that means it should only look back 12 hours as I want to search for the current days records.

How can I accomplish this in Python?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5476065/truncate-python-datetime

Comment: @NightShadeQueen so essentially set the start time to the truncated version of datetime and then use the current time for the end range. That should work.

Comment: related: [Python: Given the current time in UTC, how do you determine the start and end time of the day in a particular timezone?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25605133/4279)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I hope this makes sense, I just gave very descriptive variable names

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

now = datetime.now()
start_of_day = datetime(now.year,now.month,now.day)
delta_since_start_of_day = now - start_of_day
delta_till_end_of_day = timedelta(days=1) - delta_since_start_of_day
end_of_day = start_of_day + timedelta(days=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @J.F.Sebastian, I edited accordingly

Comment: I for more accuracy and consistency: end_of_day = start_of_day + timedelta(days=1, seconds=-1)

Answer (score 9):

Here's another solution that directly resets the time - no math required. Uses [datetime.replace():](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace)

```
now = datetime.now()
day_start = now.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
day_end = day_start + timedelta(hours=24)
```

Comment: One advantage of using `datetime.replace()` like this is that it preserves the timezone info.

Answer (score 5):

It seems you could accomplish what you wish like so:

```
from datetime import datetime, time

now = datetime.now()
start = datetime.combine(now, time.min)  # datetime.datetime(2021, 11, 5, 0, 0)
end = datetime.combine(now, time.max)  # datetime.datetime(2021, 11, 5, 23, 59, 59, 999999)
```

No need for maths, replacing, timedeltas.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It is so much cleaner to read and easier to understand what the code is doing and why.

Answer (score -1):

I just use datetime.time.max in this way:

```
now = datetime.now()
day_end = datetime.datetime.combine(now, datetime.time.max)
```